# Remove duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, duplicates

I need to delete all duplicate rows:

```
t1
--------------------
col1    col2    col3
1       a       b
2       a       c
3       a       b
```

In this example 1 and 3 are duplicates. I need to insert both to another table and then delete both from the current table.

```
t1
--------------------
col1    col2    col3
1       a       c

t2
--------------------
col1    col2    col3
1       a       b
2       a       b
```

What is the best way to do this?

**Edit**

I should provide more information. t1 is a temp table that contains rows for an import. There are 4 fields that uniquely identify a record and an additional 20+ fields for each row. If there are duplicates, they need to be inserted into a different table for review. Therefore, I don't believe the identity value needs to be preserved as once it's inserted into the system that value from the temp table will no longer be useful.

Comment: In your example, should col1 of t2 preserve the value from t1 (i.e. the second row has a typo and "2" should be "3")?

Comment: @Clark - Updated to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is useful to delete duplicate records. The table must have identity column, which will be used to identify the duplicate records. Table in example is has ID as Identity Column and Columns which have duplicate data are DuplicateColumn1, DuplicateColumn2 and DuplicateColumn3.

```
DELETE
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DuplicateColumn1, DuplicateColumn2, DuplicateColumn3)
```

Quoted from: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/01/sql-server-delete-duplicate-records-rows/

Comment: This only deletes 1 of the records.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find all of the duplicate rows would be to join the table to itself on all of the columns that could have duplicate data and filter out the rows where the col1 values are identical, like this:

```
select distinct a.col1
from t1 a inner join t1 b on a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 = b.col3
where a.col1 <> b.col1
```

You would use this to do an insert into t2 from t1 (per my comment on your question, assuming you want to preserve the col1 value from t1 in t2):

```
insert into t2 (col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, col3
from t1
where col1 in (
    select distinct a.col1
    from t1 a inner join t1 b on a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 = b.col3
    where a.col1 <> b.col1
)
```

and then a delete from t1:

```
delete t1
where col1 in (
    select distinct a.col1
    from t1 a inner join t1 b on a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 = b.col3
    where a.col1 <> b.col1
)
```

This could be made simpler by using a temporary table to hold the col1 values so that you don't have to do the self join a second time.  Using a temporary table would also be safer.  With the two separate queries each doing a self join, it's (remotely) possible to delete rows from t1 without inserting them to t2 (i.e. if new duplicates get written to t1 between when you do the insert to t2 and the delete from t1, the newly inserted rows to t1 will get matched in the second self join).

Also, for the delete, you could use t2 instead of doing the self join on t1 again (again, if my assumption is correct and you are preserving the col1 value in t2).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO T2(Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col2, Col3
FROM T1
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT * 
                FROM T1 AS T 
                WHERE   T.Col2 = T1.Col2
                    AND T.Col3 = T1.Col3
                    AND T.Col1 <> T1.Col1
            )

DELETE FROM T1 
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT * 
                FROM T2 
                WHERE   T2.Col2 = T1.Col2
                    AND T2.Col3 = T1.Col3
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

**Inserting all duplicate records into t2.**

```
insert into t2
select src.col2, src.col3 from t1 src
inner join (select t1.col2, t1.col3 from t1
            group by t1.col2, t1.col3
            having count(*) > 1) duplicates 
on src.col2 = duplicates.col2 and src.col3 = duplicates.col3
```

**Delete duplicates from t1.**

```
delete from t1
where t1.col1 in (
    select src.col1 from t1 src
        inner join (
                    select t1.col2, t1.col3 from t1
                    group by t1.col2, t1.col3
                    having count(*) > 1) duplicates
                    on src.col2 = duplicates.col2 and src.col3 = duplicates.col3
                   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * into temp(temporary table) 
 from tablename 
       group by column_name1,column_name2 
         having (count(*)>=1)
```

---  data is inserted into temp table without any duplicasi

```
drop tablename

select * into Tablename from temp
```